# Remove DLL dependency for an Application

Tags: c#, dependencies, dotnetzip

In my application, I need to Zip and Unzip some files. For that I have used DotNet Zip Library (Ionic.Zip.dll-- [DotNet Zip Lib](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) )

Everything works fine but when I take EXE of my file and try to run it from different folder, it fails to run. I have to keep Ionic.Zip.dll in the folder where my application resides. 
Is there any way out? I just want an EXE file without any strings attached.... 
Or is there any other option other than DotNet Zip Lib.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you add a reference to another assembly (e.g. a third-party DLL) to your C# project, the compiler doesn't add the contents of that assembly into your EXE; it just creates a link that says your program will need to load that DLL when it runs. It's quite normal to distribute a .NET program as an EXE file plus the DLL files that it needs.

But if you'd prefer, you can combine them into one EXE file. There are a few different tools that can merge multiple .NET assemblies into one. Have a look at [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=22914587-b4ad-4eae-87cf-b14ae6a939b0&displaylang=en) or [.NETZ](http://madebits.com/netz/).

Comment: Only answer that directly addresses the problem - doesn't explain what the problem is though (-:

Comment: @Murph: Attempted an explanation

Comment: This solution can work for any application which has this problem.... So I have edited the Title of Post.... Great!! Thanks a lot!! Now I don’t have to supply DLLs…..

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this pure C# libraries without external dependencies:

- [ZipStorer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/ZipStorer.aspx)

It can be included into your application and compiled directly into your single EXE - no external ZIP libraries needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use .net for that, have a look at [Packaging namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.aspx) or if you can use gzip format you gave a [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) for that too. Using this you'll remove the dependency from your project.

Comment: But I guess, gzip and Normal Zip files are different.

Comment: @Swanand Purankar - Packaging namespace methods use zip format. Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.zippackage.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If it is an opensource project, you can just include the source code in your project without adding a reference to the "dll".

Comment: true, this is possible.  But it's better to use ILMerge or some other merging or embedding mechanism.